# Damaged my garage - how should I repair?

Tags: garage, damage

I did a stupid thing today, and clipped the side of my garage with my car pulling in from work. The house is only a month old, which compounds my frustration.

Anyway, it looks like the vinyl trim along the siding and the metal trim along the garage were dented, but I reached behind and couldn't feel anything else out of whack, so I don't think I need to be worried about structural damage.

That said, what should I do to repair this damage - do I replace the vinyl trim, patch it, or just paint it and call it a day? What about the metal? Do I nail it in the middle to work out the bend and adhere it back to the wall, caulk it, or just paint it and move on?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is minor surface damage. If you would try to repair the dent in the channel trim, you'd probably make it worse. You could try gently tapping the side metal trim to smooth it out and then touch it up, or just skip trying to reform it and just paint it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it right, it is a process.
 You need to start by removing the siding to get to the nails that hold the damaged vinyl trim to remove the whole piece. When that is off that will expose the remaining nails that hold the front edge of the garage door wrap. Remove the garage door weatherstip and that will either expose more nails that hold the back edge of the door wrap or the weatherstripping holds it without the extra nails. That should get you so you can remove all your damaged parts.

Get new coil stock to replace the garage door wrap and rent a metal break long enough to do the whole replacement piece. Make the same cuts as the original and nail back in the same locations, no need to be exact, but get them in the same area. Find the vinyl trim at you local builders supply and copy the same cuts and replace that and reset your siding that was numbered on the back side as you took it down to ease the reinstall process.

This is a simplified explanation. If you are game to do it yourself and do it right, ask what you need and you will get help.